# Substructure in figure positioning

Tags: graphics, positioning

I have seven figures:one large (rectangle) and six small (squares). The sum of the sizes of the six small squares is equal to the size of the large rectangle.I want to put them such that it looks like to figures: the large rectangle and another rectangle made of the six squares. I want these two rectangles to sit side by side, not vertically forming a column. My current code makes a column:

```
\begin{figure}[]
\hfill
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{rectangle}
\\
 \includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{square}
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{square}  
\\
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{square}
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{square}  
 \\
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{square}
\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{square}

\end{center}
\caption{...}
 \label{fig:4}
 \end{figure}
```

What can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method for arranging material in rows and columns is with `tabular`, in this case nested ones.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}% outer tabular
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}% inner tabular for the big picture
  \includegraphics[height=3cm,width=4cm]{duck}
  \end{tabular}
  &
  \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}% inner tabular for the squares
  \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{duck}&
  \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{duck}\\
  \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{duck}&
  \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{duck}\\
  \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{duck}&
  \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{duck}
  \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\caption{Some ducks}\label{fig:ducks}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want no space, some changes are needed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\fincludegraphics}[2][]{% just for the example, to add frames
  \begingroup\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
  \fbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}

\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}% outer tabular
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}% inner tabular for the big picture
  \fincludegraphics[height=3cm,width=4cm]{duck}
  \end{tabular}
  &
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}% inner tabular for the squares
  \fincludegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{duck}&
  \fincludegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{duck}\\
  \fincludegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{duck}&
  \fincludegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{duck}\\
  \fincludegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{duck}&
  \fincludegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{duck}
  \end{tabular}
\\
\strut\footnotesize (a) & \footnotesize (b) % the subcaptions
\end{tabular}

\caption{Some ducks}\label{fig:ducks}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I added `@{}` between all pairs of columns and also set the array stretch to zero, so the rows are allowed to touch each other.

The `\fincludegraphics` macro is just for adding frames around the pictures, you should use the normal `\includegraphics`. The frames are not complete due to rounding errors.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! But, how could I put the small ducks closer to each other? Even touching each other ?

Comment: @Mencia I'll add the margins, so to show that they're indeed touching each other (after some change).

Comment: Could you also put  (a) for the big one and (b) for the group of six ?

Comment: @Mencia Done, it should be OK, now; sorry for the incomplete frames, it's just due to rounding errors.

Comment: Thanks! But I need some distance between the big duck and the group of six. The small six should touch as they do now, so that is perfect.

Comment: @Mencia Remove the middle `@{}` in the outer tabular as I did in my last edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could place the rectangle in one `minipage` and the six squares in another.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm,height=1cm]{rectangle}
\end{minipage} % note: no line break after end of minipage
\begin{minipage}{2.05cm}
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{square}\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{square}  

\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{square}\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{square}  

\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{square}\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{square}
\end{minipage}
\caption{\dots} \label{fig:4}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```